# change the size of the image for the bar button background programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uibarbuttonitem

In my Navigation bar I've put a bar button and I've set an image for the background. But the size of the image is much bigger than the size of the button. So I tried to tackle that as follow:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5 ))
        imageView.contentMode = .center

        let image = UIImage(named: "Info")
        imageView.image = image

        info_btn.image = image
    }
```

however the picture is still stretched out. Any idea how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `info_btn.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`